# Posting large Base64 strings to a server

Tags: javascript, ajax, html, image, canvas

I'm attempting to post large base64s (around 3500000 characters long) via ajax to a server side script that converts the base64 into an image. The issue is that sometimes the post times out with the server never receiving the base64. The timeout limit is currently set at 20 seconds, which I would expect is more than enough.

I don't really want to scale the image down any further as it is already at a lower resolution than I would like it to be (the images that are posted will be physically printed, so need to be reasonably high-res).

The potential solutions I can think of are:

- Reduce the resolution of the images within the canvas
- Reduce the resolution of the image created by the canvas
- Reduce the colour range of the canvas

The last one is the one that interests me the most, as I have already implemented the other two as much as I feel comfortable doing, but I'm not sure how to go about it.

Any advice or solutions on how to go about this would be appreciated. Thanks.

Comment: `The timeout limit is currently set at 20 seconds, which I would expect is more than enough.` locally ... yes ... over ADSL for example ... you'd want 40 seconds to be sure

Comment: What’s your server-side setup (language)? If it is PHP, you should find a lot of information regarding file upload limits and their configuration on SO already.

Comment: I am using PHP, but its not a file size limit issue. Our server upload limit is 20MB, and these files are not reaching anywhere near that (typically between 2-3MB).

Answer (score 1):

> • Reduce the colour range of the canvas

You can use `canvas.getImageData` and `canvas.putImageData` to do this.

Here is sample that first paints a canvas with a set of random colors

```
<canvas id="before" width="300" height="200"></canvas>
```

```
var bcanvas = document.getElementById('before')
var bctx = bcanvas.getContext("2d");

for (var i = 0; i < 300; i = i + 3) {
    var r = parseInt(Math.random() * 256)
    var g = parseInt(Math.random() * 256)
    var b = parseInt(Math.random() * 256)
    bctx.fillStyle = "rgba(" + r + ", " + g + ", " + b + ", 1)";
    bctx.fillRect(i, 0, 3, 200);
}

alert(bcanvas.toDataURL().length);
```

And then we loop through the pixels, reducing the number of colors (here we just divide each pixel's r g and b values by 16, round it down and then scale it upto 255, ending up with ~16 distinct values for each of r g and b in place of 255 each)

```
var imgData = bctx.getImageData(0, 0, 300, 200);
var pixels = imgData.data;
// if a pixel is slightly red make it full red, same for blue and green
for (var nPixel = 0; nPixel < pixels.length; nPixel += 4) {
    pixels[nPixel] = parseInt(pixels[nPixel] / 16) * 16;
    pixels[nPixel + 1] = parseInt(pixels[nPixel + 1] / 16) * 16;
    pixels[nPixel + 2] = parseInt(pixels[nPixel + 2] / 16) * 16;
}

var acanvas = document.getElementById('after')
var actx = acanvas.getContext("2d");

actx.putImageData(imgData, 0, 0);

alert(acanvas.toDataURL().length);
```

Resulting in an approximately 17% reduction in the DataURL length.

Note that this is just a "how to". You'll probably need to read up on the png image format and what kind of color optimization will have the benefit to figure out "how to" do it so that I reduce the image size.

---

Warning : alert boxes ahead. Do not panic.

```js
var bcanvas = document.getElementById('before')
var bctx = bcanvas.getContext("2d");

for (var i = 0; i < 300; i = i + 3) {
  var r = parseInt(Math.random() * 256)
  var g = parseInt(Math.random() * 256)
  var b = parseInt(Math.random() * 256)
  bctx.fillStyle = "rgba(" + r + ", " + g + ", " + b + ", 1)";
  bctx.fillRect(i, 0, 3, 200);
}

alert(bcanvas.toDataURL().length);


var imgData = bctx.getImageData(0, 0, 300, 200);
var pixels = imgData.data;
// if a pixel is slightly red make it full red, same for blue and green
for (var nPixel = 0; nPixel < pixels.length; nPixel += 4) {
  pixels[nPixel] = parseInt(pixels[nPixel] / 16) * 16;
  pixels[nPixel + 1] = parseInt(pixels[nPixel + 1] / 16) * 16;
  pixels[nPixel + 2] = parseInt(pixels[nPixel + 2] / 16) * 16;
}

var acanvas = document.getElementById('after')
var actx = acanvas.getContext("2d");

actx.putImageData(imgData, 0, 0);

alert(acanvas.toDataURL().length);
```

```html
<canvas id="before" width="300" height="200"></canvas>
<br />
<canvas id="after" width="300" height="200"></canvas>
```